# leg_detector only publish on visualization_marker and only legs, no people

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, leg-detector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im running the leg_detector in a simulated enviroment using the rbkairos. The leg detector does publish in the topics but does not detect any person or legs (in the topis /leg_tracker_measurements and /people_tracker_measurements) but it does publish in the topic /visualization_marker so i can see that its detecting the legs of the person. Does anyone have any idea why is happening that?

Thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354069/leg_detector-only-publish-on-visualization_marker-and-only-legs,-no-people/) by [Dagu](https://answers.ros.org/users/55498/dagu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try lowering the [leg_reliability_limit](http://wiki.ros.org/leg_detector#Parameters) parameter. It will publish all legs detected as markers (with varying colors of [blue](https://github.com/wg-perception/people/blob/melodic/leg_detector/src/leg_detector.cpp#L925) depending on the reliability, but only legs above the limit will be published as messages.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2020-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dagu](https://answers.ros.org/users/55498/dagu/) on 2020-06-05**:
I tried and it works but only with a very low reliability, i thing its because the simulation enviroment. Thank you very much for your help.

(At first i tried but i did it wrong)