# Leg_detector: cannot output data

Tags: ros-noetic, leg-detector

I am new to ROS and I am trying to use the [leg_detector](http://wiki.ros.org/leg_detector) package on Turtlebot3. I first launched turtlebot_bringup to get the /scan topic. Then, I launch the leg_detector package and get all topics published. Unfortunately, when I check the topics */leg_tracker_measurements*, */people_tracker_measurements*, and */visualization_marker*, there is no output data.

```
~$ rostopic list
/base_scan
/battery_state
/cmd_vel
/cmd_vel_rc100
/diagnostics
/firmware_version
/imu
/joint_states
/leg_detector/parameter_descriptions
/leg_detector/parameter_updates
/leg_tracker_measurements
/magnetic_field
/motor_power
/odom
/people_tracker_filter
/people_tracker_measurements
/reset
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/scan
/sensor_state
/sound
/tf
/tf_static
/version_info
/visualization_marker
~$ rostopic echo /leg_tracker_measurements
```

I tried the solution suggested by [this post](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/96065/leg-detector-only-publish-on-visualization-marker-and-only-legs-no-people?rq=1) by lowering the **leg_reliability_limit** param in the **LegDectector.cfg** file from 0.7 to 0.5.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator_catkin import ParameterGenerator, bool_t, double_t, int_t, str_t``

gen = ParameterGenerator()
gen.add('connection_threshold',     double_t,   0, '[m]', 0.06, 0, .25)
gen.add('min_points_per_group',     int_t,      0, '', 5, 1, 20)


gen.add('leg_reliability_limit',    double_t,   0, '', 0.5, 0, 1)
gen.add('publish_legs',             bool_t,     0, '', True)
gen.add('publish_people',           bool_t,     0, '', True)
gen.add('publish_leg_markers',      bool_t,     0, '', True)
gen.add('publish_people_markers',   bool_t,     0, '', True)

gen.add('no_observation_timeout',   double_t,   0, 'Timeout tolerance for no observations [s]', 0.5, 0, 5)
gen.add('max_second_leg_age',       double_t,   0, '[s]', 2.0, 0, 5)
gen.add('max_track_jump',           double_t,   0, '[m]', 1.0, 0, 5)
gen.add('max_meas_jump',            double_t,   0, '[m]', 0.75, 0, 5)
gen.add('leg_pair_separation',      double_t,   0, '[m]', 1.0, 0, 2)
gen.add('fixed_frame',              str_t,      0, 'Fixed Frame', 'odom_combined')

gen.add('kalman_p',                 double_t,   0, '',    4, 0, 10)
gen.add('kalman_q',                 double_t,   0, '', .002, 0, 10)
gen.add('kalman_r',                 double_t,   0, '',   10, 0, 20)
gen.add('kalman_on',                int_t,      0, '',    1, 0,  1)

exit(gen.generate('leg_detector', 'leg_detector', 'LegDetector'))
```

However, when I check the topic */leg_detector/parameter_updates*, the param **leg_reliability_limit** does not change and stay 0.7 as the default setting. I am not sure did I successfully alter the value or not?

```
~$ rostopic echo /leg_detector/parameter_updates
bools: 
  - 
    name: "publish_legs"
    value: True
  - 
    name: "publish_people"
    value: True
  - 
    name: "publish_leg_markers"
    value: True
  - 
    name: "publish_people_markers"
    value: True
ints: 
  - 
    name: "min_points_per_group"
    value: 5
  - 
    name: "kalman_on"
    value: 1
strs: 
  - 
    name: "fixed_frame"
    value: "odom_combined"
doubles: 
  - 
    name: "connection_threshold"
    value: 0.06
  - 
    name: "leg_reliability_limit"
    value: 0.7
  - 
    name: "no_observation_timeout"
    value: 0.5
  - 
    name: "max_second_leg_age"
    value: 2.0
  - 
    name: "max_track_jump"
    value: 1.0
  - 
    name: "max_meas_jump"
    value: 0.75
  - 
    name: "leg_pair_separation"
    value: 1.0
  - 
    name: "kalman_p"
    value: 4.0
  - 
    name: "kalman_q"
    value: 0.002
  - 
    name: "kalman_r"
    value: 10.0
```

Could anyone having the experience with this package help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please edit your question with your commands and any console outputs you're seeing. And include the other things you're doing to debug too. The only information we have about your system is what's written here. So we need your help to explain your system.

Comment: I edited the post with outputs from my terminal. Please let me know if you need more clarification.